# How to install package in Synaptic (Debian) without internet

Tags: linux, debian, packages

Package need to connect internet for downloading updates, but computer have not connection to internet. How I can install this package without connection internet?

Answer (score 3):

Retrieve the right .deb file from a Debian mirror (or wherever it comes from), copy it onto the target system, use "dpkg -i" (as root) to install the .deb file.

Comment: Don't forget to also download the dependencies (if needed)